# Embedding playn games in an HTML/JS app

Tags: java, html, gwt, playn

I'm exploring making a game with PlayN.  It seems awesome, but only for the game itself - I'd prefer to do menus, navigation, high-score lists, etc in HTML (with GWT, incidentally).

If I make a PlayN game, are there methods for hooking into it from the outside?  Does it have any mechanisms for communicating with containing apps, or must I do the entire application within the PlayN framework?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're only going to deploy to HTML5, then you can use all of GWT in your game and integrate as deeply as you like with the surrounding web page.

You only have to stick to the PlayN APIs if you want to deploy on other platforms like Android and iOS.

Comment: But I get the impression that the playn framework normally controls the main loop of the entire program - I want GWT to handle all of that and only use the playn loop for an embedded "game" section.  Will that work, or does playn have to be at the top level?

Comment: JavaScript/the browser controls the main loop, not PlayN nor GWT, so there's no conflict. PlayN uses requestAnimationFrame, but that will interoperate just fine with your GWT app.

Comment: So bolstered, I'll head into actually learning how PlayN works.  Thanks for the advice!